# How to Iterate over a list of dictionary and print dict if certain key has required value

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

As you can see below variable y contains a list of dictionaries which contain various details about a few persons,
I want to print the dictionary which contains the key named position = 'Account Manager'.

P.S: I'm pretty new to Python.

```
y = [{'email': 'hgibson@journeyflight.com', 'type': 'prospect', 'status': 'verified', 'firstName': 'Hannah', 'lastName': 'Gibson', 'position': 'Corporate Flight Attendant'},

 {'email': 'ncucalon@journeyflight.com', 'type': 'prospect', 'status': 'verified', 'firstName': 'Nicole', 'lastName': 'Cucalon', 'position': 'Account Manager'},

 {'email': 'shazamy@journeyflight.com', 'type': 'prospect', 'status': 'verified', 'firstName': 'Sam', 'lastName': 'Hazamy', 'position': 'Maintenance Controller and Invoicing Specialist'}, 

{'email': 'rafaelbajares@journeyflight.com', 'type': 'prospect', 'status': 'verified', 'firstName': 'Rafael', 'lastName': 'Bajares', 'position': 'Gulfstream IV Pilot'}]

for i in y:
    if i.keys.position = 'Account Manager'
    print(i)
```

### Output :

```
if i.keys() ='Account Manager':
            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `if i['position'] == 'Account Manager'` ?

Comment: Your list of dictionaries is assigned to `y`, but your for loop is iterating over `p`.

Comment: @Rakesh Thank you so much. It worked.

Comment: @BaconBits Thanks for pointing out. Edited it .

Comment: Why are you accessing dict keys by using `.`?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems to be reliant on using a dictionary that is converted to dotted format(like DotDict from Robot framework).
Usually, a dcitionary is read like this `y['position']`.

Anyway, this code should work for your requirement:

```
y = [{'email': 'hgibson@journeyflight.com', 'type': 'prospect', 'status': 'verified', 'firstName': 'Hannah', 'lastName': 'Gibson', 'position': 'Corporate Flight Attendant'},
     {'email': 'ncucalon@journeyflight.com', 'type': 'prospect', 'status': 'verified', 'firstName': 'Nicole', 'lastName': 'Cucalon', 'position': 'Account Manager'},
     {'email': 'shazamy@journeyflight.com', 'type': 'prospect', 'status': 'verified', 'firstName': 'Sam', 'lastName': 'Hazamy', 'position': 'Maintenance Controller and Invoicing Specialist'},
     {'email': 'rafaelbajares@journeyflight.com', 'type': 'prospect', 'status': 'verified', 'firstName': 'Rafael', 'lastName': 'Bajares', 'position': 'Gulfstream IV Pilot'}]

for person_dict in y:
    if person_dict.get("position", "") == "Account Manager"
        print person_dict
```